# Relationship Between Differentiation in Two Frames

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differentiation, flow, aerodynamics, calculus

In section 10.3 of **Principles of Ideal-Fluid Aerodynamics** by Karamcheti, he writes the following:

> $\qquad$ Denote by $K_1$ a reference frame fixed with respect to the moving body. We shall denote by subscript 1 all measurements and operations made with respect to frame $K_1$. The space fixed reference frame shall be denoted by $K$, and the measurements and operations made with respect to $K$ shall be denoted without any subscript.
>   $\qquad$ We now set up the connection between the descriptions in the two frames (Fig. 10.1). since $K_1$ is translating with a velocity $\mathbf{U}(t)$ with respect to $K$ we have, assuming that the two frames are coincident at time zero,
>
> $$\mathbf{r}_1=\mathbf{r}_1(\mathbf{r},t)=\mathbf{r}-\int_0^t\mathbf{U}(\tau)d\tau$$
>   $$t_1=t_1(\mathbf{r},t)=t$$
>   $\vdots$
>   $\qquad$The various different operations in the two frames are related as follows:
>
> $$\nabla=\nabla_1$$
>   $$\nabla^2=\nabla_1^2$$
>   $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial t_1}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial t_1}+\frac{\partial \mathbf{r}_1}{\partial t}\bullet\nabla_1$$

Can anyone explain/derive the last formula? It resembles the material derivative (also known as the substantial or total derivative), but Karamcheti generally dennotes the material derivative as $\frac{D}{Dt}$. I can upload a picture of Fig. 10.1 if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assume a quantity $\Phi$ that can be **represented in both coordinate systems**, - the reference (no index) and the moving frame (index 1) - and look at how it changes.

If we consider the quantity $\Phi (\mathbf{r_1}, t_1)$ in a moving frame with position $\mathbf{r_1}$ and time $t_1$ and ask ourselves how it changes with respect to the reference frame with variables $\mathbf{r}$ and $t$ we have to treat the two **variables in the moving frame as dependent on the reference frame** $\mathbf{r_1} (\mathbf{r}, t)$ and $t_1 (t)$.

If we look at the change of the quantity $\Phi$ in time which is strictly a partial derivative and not a total derivative as the quantity may also vary in space according to its location $\mathbf{r}$

$$\frac{\partial \Phi (\mathbf{r_1}, t_1)}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial \Phi [\mathbf{r_1} (\mathbf{r}, t), t_1 (t)]}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial \Phi (\mathbf{r}, t)}{\partial t}.$$

Using the **chain rule** we obtain

$$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial t} = \underbrace{ \sum\limits_{i \in \mathcal{D}} \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial r_{1_i}} \frac{\partial r_{1_i}}{\partial t} }_{\frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial t} \cdot \mathbf{\nabla_1} \Phi} + \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial t_1} \frac{d t_1}{d t}.$$

**Partial or total differential?**

The **total differential** $d$ is used for quantities that are only a function of one variable (**univariate**) while **partial derivative** $\partial$ is used for functions of multiple variables (**multivariate**) where you hold all other variables fixed while you change one.

The **partial derivatives can lead to confusion here** as there are two layers of parameters. We have the function $\Phi$ which is a function of two parameters $\mathbf{r}_1$ and $t_1$ in the moving frame which are again functions of the two parameters in the reference frame $\mathbf{r}$ and $t$. So every derivative is in fact only a partial derivative! For $t_1 = t$ the above notation would be contradictory as the last term would degenerate to $\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial t}$ which has a different meaning than the first partial derivative in time: Different terms are held constant during differentiation. $\mathbf{r}$ is always constant but $\mathbf{r_1}$ or $t_1$ as a whole might be as well.

More precisely one would have to write **which terms are held constant during differentiation**

$$\frac{\partial \Phi (\mathbf{r} = const, t)}{\partial t} = \sum\limits_{i \in \mathcal{D}} \frac{\partial \Phi [\mathbf r_1 (\mathbf{r}=const, t), t_1 (t) = const]}{\partial r_{1_i}} \frac{\partial r_{1_i}}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial \Phi[\mathbf{r_1} (\mathbf{r}, t) = const, t_1 (t)]}{\partial t_1} \frac{d t_1}{d t}.$$

As this is too complicated to write a lot of derivations neglect that the quantity might also change in space and write the first derivative in time with a total differential $d$ or with the material derivative $D$ instead of the partial.

Comment: thanks! Should Karamcheti have used the script d ($d$) as you did instead of the partial symbol ($\partial$) in the last formula? Because $\frac{d\Phi}{dt}\ne\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial t}$...right?

Comment: I changed the derivation to Karamcheti's nomenclature and simplified it. The **total differential** $d$ is used for quantities that are only a function of one variable (**univariate**) while **partial derivative** $\partial$ is used for functions of multiple variables (**multivariate**) where you hold all other variables fixed while you change one. Strictly speaking the derivative should be partial as it may vary for different points in space but often in literature it is written as the total derivative.

Comment: I added an explanation to which terms are held constant. The way Karamcheti has written it is mathematically correct but somewhat **ambiguous** and not clear. Generally authors use the total derivative which is mathematically strictly speaking not correct but it is less ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you for the additional explanation! In the second term of the last equation, how can you vary $\mathbf{r}_1(\mathbf{r}=const,t)$ while keeping $\mathbf{t}_1(\mathbf{r}=const,t)=const$? This seems like a contradiction to me.

Comment: You are welcome and thanks for the edit. It was a copy and paste mistake now it should be fine. Additionally in this case we only need $t_1$ to be a function of $t$ and not $r$ as well.

Comment: By taking the partial derivative wrt $t$, aren't you implying **ALL** other variables are held constant, including $\mathbf{r}_1$. So the first term should be zero leaving only the second term. By allowing all variables to change aren't you taking the total derivative? If you havn't seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3270436/646300), it's has one of the best explinations I've seen on derivatives.

Comment: You are right, you hold all other variables constant. The only other variable in this case is $\mathbf{r}$ (!) - $\mathbf{r_1}$ and $t_1$ are **reparametrisations**. The two systems, moving and reference, are like two coordinate system that you have shifted and rotated but that still lie in the same plane, they are dependent, you just express them differently. $\mathbf{r_1}$ is a function of $t$: If you vary $t$ also $\mathbf{r_1}$ changes - you can never keep one constant while the other does not change. The system is sufficiently described by two parameters!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100827/discussion-between-eball-and-2b-t).